# CALayer not rendering background color on devices, works in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, calayer, cagradientlayer

I've created a custom button out of layers. I create a bunch of layers in `init`.  Everything works as expected until I go to modify* them.  It is only on the actual devices that the problem occurs, on the simulator the code works as expected.

I've tried forcing the layers to render by setting needsDisplay and needsLayout to `YES`.

```
-(void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{   
    //return; // if I return here, the button gets initialized with it's default royal blue color.  This works correctly on the simulator and device

    [primaryBackground setColors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)backgroundColor.CGColor]];

    //return; //if I return here, primaryBackground will display a clear background on the device, but will display CGColor on the simulator.

    CALayer* ll = [CALayer layer];
    ll.frame=self.frame;
    ll.cornerRadius=primaryBackground.cornerRadius;
    [ll setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor.CGColor];
    [primaryBackground addSublayer:ll];

     //if I return here, primaryBackground will display the "expected" results on both platforms.  IE: it dispalys the new layer, but not it's background color.
}
```

**SIMULATOR**

[image: simulator screenshot]

**DEVICE**

[image: device screenshot]

**TESTS**

I've tested on iOS 5.1 and 4.2 with the same results.  Appears to work the same on simulators version 4.1, 4.2 and 5.1

Comment: Post code or it didn't happen.

Comment: Also what version of iOS Device and iOS Simulator.

Comment: make sure to export the images as .png with a normal RGB profile. Maybe you have a weird color profile?!

Comment: As I went through and pared down the code I was able to hone in on the problem.  I thought the slate grey color was different than the background, but that's just an optical illusion - it's the same color.    The BG color is just getting "erased" on the device side of things.

Comment: Shouldn't you be casting the `backgroundColor.CGColor`to `(id)` ? `(id)backgroundColor.CGColor`. Just maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 problems with your code:

1. You are adding a new layer every time the color is changed, without removing the old one. First, remove the previously created sublayer (or simply change its color without creating and adding a new one). Remember that the default `opaque` property of `CALayer` is set to `NO`, which means it is being blended with all the other sublayers.

   **Why adding another sublayer anyway?** In your code, you cover `primaryBackground` completely. Can't `setBackgroundColor:` function just look like this:

   ```
   - (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor { 
       [primaryBackground setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor.CGColor];
   }
   ```

   ?
2. But if you really must have an additional layer, you should set `ll`'s `frame` to the `bounds` of the `superlayer` (not `frame`). It should be `ll.frame = self.bounds`. You should also override the `- (void)layoutSubivews` method and set the `frame` of the background layer to the bounds of the root layer again.

Remember that, on *iPhone Simulator*, things are rendered by different subsystem and a lot faster than on real device. And some frame calculations may overlap, etc.

Comment: I'll try setting the size in layoutSubviews, though as far as I remember the size was the size I expected.